# Getting the time of compilation using Python in Ubuntu

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, time, ubuntu-16.04

I am implementing a multi-threading code in python. This example is printing a message every 2 seconds. The output of the terminal in Ubuntu is not logical compared to the result of Pycharm in Windows 10. I think that `time` module should work in both environments. I do not know why it is not working in Linux.
Also, is there other module similar to `time` to be used ?

I appreciate your help

Code:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from time import clock as clk
## To create a thread in Python you'll want to make your class work as a thread.
## For this, you should subclass your class from the Thread class
s2 = 0
class Book(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.message = ("Hello Parallel Python!!\n")

    def print_message(self):
        print (self.message)

##The run method prints the message
    def run(self):
        print ("Thread Starting")
        x=0
        while (x < 10):
            self.print_message()
            sleep(2)
            print "Time is : ", clk()
            x += 1
        print ("Thread Ended\n")
        s2 = clk()
        print "2st s2 is: ", s2

#start the main process
print ("Process Started")

# create an instance of the HelloWorld class
hello = Book()

# print the message...starting the thread
s1 = clk()
hello.start()

#end the main process
print ("Process Ended\n")
print "1st s2 is: ", s2
```

The output using Pycharm in Windows 10 is:

[Pycharm result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RCA0.jpg)

The output using gedit in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is:

[terminal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkbP3.png)

Comment: Please [read the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.clock) before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you got `timeit` it is a module that can be used for execution time calculation.

you can try following updated code to check that .

```
import timeit
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from time import clock as clk
## To create a thread in Python you'll want to make your class work as a thread.
## For this, you should subclass your class from the Thread class
s2 = 0
class Book(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.message = ("Hello Parallel Python!!\n")

    def print_message(self):
        print (self.message)

##The run method prints the message
    def run(self):
        timeAtStart = timeit.default_timer()
        start_time = timeit.default_timer()
        print ("Thread Starting")
        x=0
        while (x < 10):
            self.print_message()
            sleep(2)
            x += 1
            print(timeit.default_timer() - start_time)
            start_time = timeit.default_timer()
        print ("Thread Ended\n")

        print("2st s2 is: ", timeit.default_timer()-timeAtStart)

#start the main process
print ("Process Started")

# create an instance of the HelloWorld class
hello = Book()

# print the message...starting the thread
hello.start()
```

Here are some results :

**For Windows :**

```
Hello Parallel Python!!

2.0153833086419755
Hello Parallel Python!!

2.0137947654320985
Hello Parallel Python!!

2.0127004444444445
Hello Parallel Python!!

2.0082500740740743
Hello Parallel Python!!

2.0016956049382717
Hello Parallel Python!!

2.012038716049382
Hello Parallel Python!!

2.014874469135803
Hello Parallel Python!!

2.0006115555555546
Hello Parallel Python!!
```

**For Linux(Ubuntu)**

```
Hello Parallel Python!!

2.00243210793
Hello Parallel Python!!

2.00301098824
Hello Parallel Python!!

2.00235509872
Hello Parallel Python!!

2.00234389305
Hello Parallel Python!!

2.00045418739
Hello Parallel Python!!

2.00276589394
Hello Parallel Python!!

2.00276899338
Hello Parallel Python!!
```

Answer (score 0):

[`time.clock`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.clock) measures different things on different systems. On your Linux system, it doesn't count time spent sleeping.

The best function to use for measuring elapsed realtime depends on your OS and Python version. [`timeit.default_timer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.default_timer) is a good default for OS and Python version independence.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Thumbs up